# Multiple authors delimiter

Tags: csl

How can I change the delimiter in case of multiple authors (preferably) in the [visual CSL editor](https://editor.citationstyles.org/visualEditor/).

Currently, the inline citation is as follows:

> (Hawking 1966; Nußholz & Whalen 2019)

What I want is to replace `&` with `,`:

> (Hawking 1966; Nußholz, Whalen 2019)

I cannot find the respective field in the visual code editor. When searching through the code in the code editor, I found `&amp;`only four times and I think none of the instances is related to what I want to change.

I've also tried to place the following code (as explained [here](https://www.zotero.org/support/dev/citation_styles/style_editing_step-by-step)) into my style but it is not working:

```
<names variable="author">
  <name form="short" delimiter="/"/>
  ..
</names>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to answer this without seeing the style in questions, but in basic terms what you need to do is to completely remove `and="symbol"` from the `name` element for the in text citation.

In the visual editor, you'd click on the names of the in-text citation at the top right, then click on "Name" at the top left, and then in the bottom right find "and" (the second from the top under "Name" and set it from symbol to empty.

Comment: I didn't find the field in the visual editor but I manually removed **all** `and="symbol"`  in the visual editor and then it worked. Thanks!